# How can I test and quantify the change in distribution over multiple years?

Tags: time-series, t-test

I have a data set of energy usage values taken every half hour for a year, for four years.

How can I test for, and quantify, an improvement (i.e. decrease) in energy usage, per-year?
I have initially assessed the data via histograms and the use of standard deviation. I initially assumed I could use a t-test, though from my current understanding it seems that that could test one year into the next, but not across all four?

I have a very strong understanding of excel (though no vba, yet), and a smattering of R. Provided there is a suitable test, I will be attempting to implement it in one of these two.

I'm looking for something related to change in distribution, standard deviation and mean, not only as I would understand it, but also this needs to be explainable to non-statisticians. Assume that the distribution of data across the year is normal (it practically is).

Comment: What does your initial assessment look like? Did you, for example, break the data into groups of contiguous times and explore the distributions?  Did that exploration give clear results?

Comment: @whuber As it is data from buildings, they follow a regular yearly, seasonal cycle, so the data was split into individual years.
Initial analysis showed there was a difference between these groups, both in the mean, and distribution around it.
An ideal solution would be a method to quantify the change in the mean and distribution, which can then be applied to similar data sets from other buildings.

Comment: That sounds like a good approach. You will need to decide which aspects of the distributions you want to compare in addition to their means and SDs.  You might also consider whether it would be more meaningful first to remove any secular trend (which would be captured by comparing the annual means) and consistent seasonal variation (which might mask interesting aspects of the shapes of the residual distributions). Normality is not an issue. Moreover, you might have little need for formal testing when means are clearly changing: maybe you just need good descriptive statistics.

Comment: @whuber from my googling of secular trends, I'm not sure removing them would be useful, or even possible with the available data, though worth baring in mind, thank you.

As for consistent seasonal variation, in our case this is a directly driving force (energy usage of buildings and annual weather cycles are intrinsically linked), what method would remove them? By removing them it seems like you may miss out on the variable that all this derives from?

As the end result is to quantify improvement, a comparison of distribution via box and whisker may suit? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Quantifying secular trends is as easy as making a robust fit of a simple function over time. The reasons to account for seasonal variation are plain, as you say: if you do not, then you confound that variation with other variations of interest. Of course I am not suggesting that you *ignore* either the secular trend or the seasonal variation--far from it!--but that it can be fruitful to analyze your data into these components. The resulting description of changes of distribution over time would then be comprised of a long-term trend, a seasonal cycle, *plus* other forms of variation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have time series data, your data is auto-correlated thus this means you have violated the independence assumption underlying the t test. I suggest that you build an ARMAX model at a higher level of aggregation say monthly. Use Intervention Detection schemes along with an ARIMA structure to identify to test for a possible mean shift or change in trend over the 48 months.

Comment: Thanks for the quick (and detailed!) response. There is currently plan to apply ARIMA analysis to this data set at a later point, but the current objective is to find a simple analysis that can be simply understood with GCSE/A level maths.

Comment: There is no "simple analysis" in my opinion . One must identify and incorporate memory structure (ARIMA) and any needed deterministic variables such as pulses/level shifts/seasonal pulses/local time trends that are either user-suggested or empirically detected.

Comment: Thank's anyway. I would 'vote' you up for the help, but my rep isn't high enough to let me apparently :(

Comment: *Of course* there is a simple analysis. The real question is whether it will be helpful for the intended task and not potentially misleading.  Not every dataset has to be analyzed as an ARMAX model, even when it happens to be a time series.

Comment: What you say is true if there is intermittent data otherwise please provide an example of a time series that doesn't fit the paradigm of an ARMAX model.

Comment: @DaveRGP As you get around to modelling half-hour data take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125587/how-to-predict-the-time-series-data/125597#125597 for some guidance with respect to modelling ...

Comment: That challenge sounds like the proverbial nail: whatever it is, if I produce it, you will hammer it! The point is that a time series is never ARMAX: it's *your model of it* that is ARMAX. And I don't question your ability to model any set of data--whether it's a time series or not!--using that tool. What does matter, though, is *how effective* and *how useful for a particular purpose* that model may be. In this case, the OP has signaled that a simple, readily interpretable (yet presumably accurate) analysis will have more value than a complex model.

Comment: Complex is in the eye of the beholder and a relative term.I agree that a simple answer/approach was requested but a simply wrong method like a t test deserved my warning.